# Comando funciona en la consola pero no dentro de un script

Tags: bash

Haciendo un script utilizando una variable de nombre `ALEATORIO` para obtener un número aleatorio en un rango entre el 1 y el 10, utilicé la siguiente línea:

```
ALEATORIO=$(($RANDOM%10+1))
```

Al ejecutar, me devuelve un error:

> aleatorio: **arithmetic expression: expecting primary: "%10"***

Sin embargo, al ejecutarlo en la consola funciona bien, tanto imprimiendo la variable con echo o directamente con la expresión.

Comment: No veo un error evidente. ¿Cómo ejecutas el script? ¿Has usado https://www.shellcheck.net/ para revisar si hay algún error?

Comment: No conocía Shellcheck. Como es posible que esa gente aún no tenga el Nóbel? : ) . Por lo visto la sintaxis correcta es ALEATORIO = $((RANDOM%10+1)). Sigo sin entender por qué funciona en línea de comando y no en el script, pero solucionó el problema. El script entero sigue sin funcionar por otros motivos, pero quiero darme una oportunidad de resolverlo solo sin recurrir al primo de zumosol :)...pero no te vayas muy lejos por si acaso. Muchas gracias Hernán, me has salvado.

Answer (score 0):

Si estás corriendo exactamente ese comando dentro de tu script como dentro de tu consola, lo que se me hace más obvio es que **la shell que corres de forma interactiva (tú "consola", no es la misma que ejecuta aquella línea)**.

No sé con qué shell la estés corriendo, pero supondré que usas `bash` o `zsh`:

```
$ zsh -c 'ALEATORIO=$(($RANDOM%10+1)); echo $ALEATORIO' # Usamos zsh
3  # Todo bien
$ bash -c 'ALEATORIO=$(($RANDOM%10+1)); echo $ALEATORIO' # Usamos bash
4  # De nuevo, todo bien
```

Sin embargo, si usamos otra, por ejemplo, `dash`, veamos qué sucede:

```
$ dash -c 'ALEATORIO=$(($RANDOM%10+1)); echo $ALEATORIO'
dash: 1: arithmetic expression: expecting primary: "%10+1"
```

Ahora usemos el siempre tan misterioso `sh`:

```
$ sh -c 'ALEATORIO=$(($RANDOM%10+1)); echo $ALEATORIO'
sh: 1: arithmetic expression: expecting primary: "%10+1
```

Y notamos un error semejante en ambos, ¿Por qué?

Veamos quién está detrás del `sh`:

```
$ readlink -f $(command -v sh)
/bin/dash
```

Y vemos que `sh` es tan sólo un nombre, un enlace simbólico para la primitiva shell, `dash`.

En otras palabras, no hacías lo mismo desde tu consola (supongo que es `bash`) que dentro del script (porque puede que este script sea ejecutada por `dash` o otra consola que no soporte esa sintaxis u operación).

### Conclusión

Cuando corras un script, ten cuidado de con qué shell lo haces:

```
$ bash <script>
$ zsh <script>
$ sh <script>  # Recordando que sh es un "alias" para dash.
$ ./<script>   #  En este caso, tan sólo lo tomamos como un ejecutable y deberá
               #+ tener permisos de ejecución y un header que indique el programa
               #+ con el que deberá ser corrido como complemento del número mágico.
```

Para evitar este tipo de problemas, puedes indicar en la cabecera de tu script la cadena: `#!<ruta de tu programa que lo ejecutará>`, por ejemplo:

```
#!/bin/bash
... script de bash
```

Otro ejemplo:

```
 #!/bin/sed -nf
 # Esto se ejecutará utilizando al comando sed
 s/hola/adios/
 p
```

Comment: Gracias por la explicación tan detallada. Veo que poco menos he estado perdiendo el tiempo mezclando conceptos.

Comment: Alguna sugerencia de por donde debería empezar para aprender el Bash?

Comment: Bash es muy extraño. No veo la importancia de aprenderlo "bien" a menos que te encuentres dedicado a la automatización o te encante. En todo caso, hay una guía que te puede ayudar a profundizar muchísimos conceptos: https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/abs-guide.pdf . También puedes leer el manual de bash en `man bash`. Pero mejor es realizar ejercicios que se te ocurran.